# RegionPlot3D in cylindrical or spherical coordinates?

Tags: graphics3d, regions

RegionPlot3D is awesome. Unfortunately, it appears to work only for Cartesian coordinates. While there are ways to draw surfaces in spherical or cylindrical coordinates, I can't find a way to draw solids. Is there a way to do so that doesn't involve translating the equations to Cartesian coordinates? Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can always hide away the coordinate transformations inside a function that calls `RegionPlot3D`. Here's a quick & dirty `sphericalRegionPlot3D`:

```
sphericalRegionPlot3D[
  ineq_, {r_, rmin_: 0, rmax_: 1}, {th_, thmin_: 0, thmax_}, {ph_, 
   phmin_, phmax_}, opts___] := RegionPlot3D[With[{
     r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2],
     th = ArcCos[z/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]],
     ph = ArcTan[x, y] + Pi},
    ineq && rmin <= r <= rmax && thmin <= th <= thmax && 
     phmin <= ph <= phmax],
   {x, -rmax, rmax}, {y, -rmax, rmax}, {z, -rmax, rmax},
   MeshFunctions -> {Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2 + #3^2] &, ArcTan[#1, #2] &, 
     ArcCos[#3/Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2 + #3^2]] &}, opts];

SetAttributes[sphericalRegionPlot3D, HoldAll];
```

Example:

```
sphericalRegionPlot3D[
 Mod[ph, Pi/3] < Pi/6, {r, 2, 3}, {th, 1, Pi}, {ph, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> {3, 60, 30}]
```

[image]

Comment: And, it should work in V8 or even earlier.

Comment: I want to upvote this answer but I don't like the coding.  What's going on with `r`, `th`, `ph`?  You never localized these.  Yet, you *did* localize `x`, `y`, `z` which you should not have as these are already localized by `RegionPlot3D`. I know you can do better.

Answer (score 18):

While not positive, I believe the answer is that `RegionPlot` does *not* support spherical (or other non-Cartesian) coordinates natively.

If correct, I guess the question becomes "What's the easiest way to plot a region defined in terms of spherical coordinates, without resorting to converting the equations by hand?"  V9 has commands to ease this process.

Here are a couple of examples that show how you can use the `TransformedField` field command to convert your expression and you can use `CoordinateTransform` to generate a mesh that reflects the coordinate system that you want.

```
sphericalExpression = 1 + rho^2 - 2 rho*Cos[theta] Sin[phi];
cartesianExpression = 
 TransformedField["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", 
  sphericalExpression, {rho, phi, theta} -> {x, y, z}]
meshFunctions = Function /@ CoordinateTransform[
   "Cartesian" -> "Spherical", {#1, #2, #3}]
RegionPlot3D[cartesianExpression < 1, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 MeshFunctions -> meshFunctions, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 8,
  ViewPoint -> {2, 0, 3}, Boxed -> False, 
 AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, -1}}]
```

[image]

I've cranked up `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` since mesh lines are fairly complicated on the other side of the figure.

```
Show[%, ViewPoint -> {-3, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

That example was chosen to yield a simple expression in Cartesian coordinates. Arbitrary expressions might yield numerical warnings but generally work.  If you'd like to constrain your figure to lie within a sphere, you can do so by including a `x^2+y^2+z^2<1` in your region specification.

```
sphericalExpression = Sin[rho] + Cos[theta]*phi;
cartesianExpression = 
 TransformedField["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", 
   sphericalExpression, {rho, phi, theta} -> {x, y, z}] // Simplify
RegionPlot3D[
  cartesianExpression < 1 && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 
   1}, {z, -1, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 5, PlotPoints -> 50,
  MeshFunctions -> meshFunctions] // Quiet
```

[image]

Comment: Right. I think the answer is: "no, that capability is not explicitly supported", although I am not so certain of that that I wanted to put it in my answer - particularly, given V9's new capabilities.  Thus, my answer addresses the simplest way I know of to go from a rho, phi, theta expression to a region plot.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have 9 yet, but perhaps I will download it for this capability. Really too bad that the 3D graphics set is not symmetric around usual choices of coordinate systems.

Comment: @rogerl I had the same interpretation of your question as Nasser. Is that indeed what you intended?

Comment: Yes, that is what I intended. I think this answer is responsive to the intent of my question.

Comment: @rogerl Clearly, the situation could be better. It should be possible, at least, to draw mesh lines that are indicative to your chosen coordinate system. Would that be of interest?

Answer (score 12):

More generalized version:

```
 newRegionPlot3D[
   expr_, {u_, umin_, umax_}, {v_, vmin_, vmax_}, {w_, wmin_, wmax_}, tr_, opts___] := 
 Module[{x, y, z, newExpr, xyz}, 
  newExpr = TransformedField[tr -> "Cartesian", expr, {u, v, w} -> {x, y, z}];
  xyz = CoordinateTransform[tr -> "Cartesian", {u, v, w}];
  {xmax, ymax, zmax} = NMaxValue[{#, 
       umin < u < umax && vmin < v < vmax && wmin < w < wmax}, {u, v, w}] & /@ xyz;
  {xmin, ymin, zmin} = NMinValue[{#, umin < u < umax && vmin < v < vmax && wmin < w < wmax}, {u, v, w}] & /@ xyz;
  RegionPlot3D[
   newExpr, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, {z, zmin, zmax}, opts]
]
```

Some examples:

```
newRegionPlot3D[r < 1, {r, 0, 1}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, {th, 0, Pi}, "Spherical"]
newRegionPlot3D[ro < 1, {ro, 0, 1}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, {z, 0, 1}, "Cylindrical"]
```

[image]

Comment: your generalized version is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!